# How to create 2 columns with the content inside left column aligned with container padding and second column full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am having a design that is, left side column is aligned with container padding and right side column is in full width that touches the scroll. Below is the design.

[image]

How to achieve the above design in bootstrap. I have tried using the below code.

```html
<div class='container me-0'>
  <div class='row align-items-center'>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
      <h1>Application Development</h1>
      <p className='mb-0'>
        Craft innovative applications tailored to clients with latest programming techniques.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-7'>
      <img src='/assets/images/services1.png' alt='Contact' style="width: 100%"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap 5 and it should be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, this is what I guess in this moment, expected design with full responsivness (image should never overlaps with text)

Hope it helps, good luck!

```css
.invisible-image {
  /** just to align the text */
   visibility: hidden !important;
}

.section-container {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  /** just to put the text over the image */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.image-right-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-right {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section-container">
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Application Development</h1>
        <p className="mb-0">
            Craft innovative applications tailored to clients with latest programming techniques.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"
        alt="Contact" class="d-block invisible-image img-fluid" />
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="image-right-container d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end w-100">
       <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"
          alt="Contact" class="image-right d-block" />
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]